# Datatables - Send Parameter dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatables

I created datatable like below;

```
var costtable = $('#productcategories').DataTable({
    "responsive": true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "deferRender": true,
    "ajax": "{{ route('product-json') }}?{!! \Request::getQueryString() !!}",
.....
```

I need to add/change some parameters with dynamic actions.
Like;

```
$('body').on('change', '.blabla', function(){
var val = $(this).val();
costtable.addparameter('blabla', val);
});
```

How can I make it possible?
I will use that parameter on backend.

Comment: We're going to need more detail to be able to help you. Exactly what parameter are you trying to change? Check the datatables documentation, it's very thorough: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

Comment: actually i want to add "user_id" parameters to ajax data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the *string* form of the DataTables [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option like this...

```js
"ajax": "your_url_here"
```

...you can use the *object* form of the syntax:

```js
"ajax": {
  "url": "your_url_here",
  "data": extraRequestParams
}
```

Based on the question, the object you need to construct will be:

```js
extraRequestParams = { user_id: "some_value" }
```

...where the value is what you populate from your `var val = $(this).val();`.

This data will be added to the request data which DataTables automatically generates to support server-side processing:

```
draw=1&...&start=0&length=25&user_id=some_value
```

In order for your `onchange` event to trigger the ajax call, you will need to refer to the DataTable - so, something like this:

```js
var extraRequestParams = {};

$('body').on('change', '.blabla', function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  extraRequestParams = { user_id: val };
  costtable.ajax.reload();
});
```

This assumes `costtable` is defined as your DataTable:

```js
var costtable = $('#example').DataTable( { ... } );
```

See [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) for reference.